# Using this. or super. when calling a method that exist in a superclass and a subclass

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, reference, this

There is a class called Champion who have an array of Skill as an instance variable.

It implement a method called "public final Skill[] getSkills()" where Skill[] is an array of another object called Skill.

There is a subclass called Support that implement a method called "public final boolean canHeal()" that check the array of skills in the method canHeal.

Should I write" Skill[] x = this.getSkills() " or : Skill[] x = super.getSkills() " to get the array of Skill and why ?

Keep in mind that the method getSkills is only defined in class Champion and not overridden in class Support.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `super` keyword allows you to call the base class' version of a method that your class overrode or shadowed.

If you class doesn't have a separate `getSkills()` method, `super` will have no effect.

Comment: so wether i write this. or super. they will do the same, right ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is better to  call the function without `super`.

First of all - for now there is now difference.
In the future, if you'll override this function in your class it will be hard to spot (or at least need attention).

In case you override your function, you might want to call `super.getSkills()` inside it.

Comment: Right, `super` breaks the virtual aspect of every method in Java. So better only use if if you need to break this.

Answer (score 0):

You should do neither. Adding `this.` is just superfluous and adding `super.` is likely to break your class if in the future you override `getSkills()`. So just do:

```
Skill[] x = getSkills();
```

In the current situation it will simply call the method defined in the superclass, if in the future you have a reason to override `getSkills()` (eg because your class uses a different way, or has additional conditions), it will be used automatically; which is more likely to be the correct behavior than continuing to call the superclass method.

In general you should only call `super.someMethod()` inside the overridden method if you need it (eg to not duplicate some logic or side-effects). Using it in another method should only be done if you are sure that you don't want your own implementation, but that of your superclass.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use either since Support is a Champion, but using the super.getSkills would make the code more clear that you are calling a method in the superclass.

Comment: It is more likely to add bugs if in the future the `getSkills()` method gets overridden in this class (or in its subclass).